# Como Executar JavaScript na Engine Nashorn do Java 8 Programaticamente

Tags: javascript, java, script, java-8, jvm

A partir do Java 8 passamos a ter uma nova Engine para execução de JavaScript, trata-se da Nashorn.

Quais classes da plataforma Java SE  estão envolvidas na descobrimento da engine e execução de Scripts?

Como executar JavaScript através do das próprias classes em Java neste novo interpretador?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A API que deve ser utilizada para acessar o Engine Nashorn é **javax.script**

O identificador para acesso a Engine, `"nashorn"` - Lembrando que a engine está disponível a partir do Java SE 8, ou seja, em versões prévias om código abaixo não funcionará.

> Quais classes da plataforma Java SE estão envolvidas na descobrimento da engine
>   e execução de Scripts?

A primeira classe envolvida é **javax.script.ScriptEngineManager** - Esta classe tem a responsabilidade de implementar o descobrimento e obtenção de instâncias da segunda classe importante para nosso exemplo - **javax.script.ScriptEngine**.

**ScriptEngineManager**

Como o nome da classe sugere, um objeto dela se encarrega de gerenciar não apenas a engine nashorn, mas também outras engines disponíveis.

**ScriptEngine**

De maneira simplificada, podemos dizer que esta classe modela a Engine em si própria fornecendo métodos para execução dos Scritps, tanto da Nashorn quanto de outras engines. Entre seus principais métodos estão o `ScriptEngine.eval(Reader reader)` e `ScriptEngine.eval(String script)`. O primeiro aceita um `Reader`, ao qual é possível passar um ccript de arquivo externo para ser executado. O segundo, uma `String` com as expressões. Resumindo, o objeto de `ScriptEngine` é o ponto de entrada para o interpretador Nashorn, devemos obter uma instância dele utilizando um `ScriptEngineManager`.

**ScriptException**

É uma exceção lançada pelo método `eval` e importante capturá-la para tratar problemas com o script.

> Como executar JavaScript através do das próprias classes em Java neste
>   novo interpretador?

**Exemplo**

```java
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            engine.eval("function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }");
            System.out.println(engine.eval("sum(1, 2);"));
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            System.out.println("Error executing script: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```